# Error trying to create Url Rewrite Rule from Azure Devops

Tags: iis, https, azure-devops

I am using an azure devops step to try create https redirect rule in IIS using the Manage IIS task.

I am using the following "Additional appcmd.exe commands"

```
set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='http_redirect',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost

set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules.[name='http_redirect'] /match.url:"(.*)" /match.ignoreCase:true /commit:apphost

set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules.[name='http_redirect'].conditions/add /+"[input='{HTTPS}',pattern='off']" /commit:apphost

set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules.[name='http_redirect'].action /+"[type='Redirect',url='https://{HOST_NAME}/{R:1}',redirectType='Found']" /commit:apphost
```

It seems that the first command runs as a blank rule is created, but the second one fails trying to find the rule by the name **http_redirect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below command to set URL rewrite globally:

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /+"[name='http_redirect']" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /[name='http_redirect'].match.url:"(.*)"  /commit:apphost

appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /+"[name='http_redirect'].conditions.[input='{HTTPS}',pattern='off']" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /[name='http_redirect'].action.type:"Redirect" /[name='http_redirect'].action.url:"https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" /[name='http_redirect'].action.redirectType:"Found"  /commit:apphost
```

[image]

[image]

Note: do not use {HOST_NAME},use {HTTP_HOST}.

to apply for specific site use this command:

```
appcmd.exe set config "aspsite" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='http_redirect']" /commit:apphost


appcmd.exe set config "aspsite" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /[name='http_redirect'].match.url:"(.*)"  /commit:apphost


appcmd.exe set config "aspsite" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /+"[name='http_redirect'].conditions.[input='{HTTPS}',pattern='off']" /commit:apphost


appcmd.exe set config "aspsite" -section:system.webServer/rewrite/rules /[name='http_redirect'].action.type:"Redirect" /[name='http_redirect'].action.url:"https://{HOST_NAME}/{R:1}" /[name='http_redirect'].action.redirectType:"Found"  /commit:apphost
```

[image]

Edit:
power-shell command to add rule:

```
import-module webAdministration
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webserver/rewrite/GlobalRules" -name "." -value @{name='HTTP to HTTPS Redirect'; patternSyntax='ECMAScript'; stopProcessing='True'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webserver/rewrite/GlobalRules/rule[@name='HTTP to HTTPS Redirect']/match" -name url -value "(.*)"
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webserver/rewrite/GlobalRules/rule[@name='HTTP to HTTPS Redirect']/conditions" -name "." -value @{input="{HTTPS}"; pattern='^OFF$'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/rule[@name='HTTP to HTTPS Redirect']/action" -name "type" -value "Redirect"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/rule[@name='HTTP to HTTPS Redirect']/action" -name "url" -value "https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules/rule[@name='HTTP to HTTPS Redirect']/action" -name "redirectType" -value "SeeOther"
```

Comment: thanks, to make this repeatable i would need to remove the rule first if it exists already, what command would i use for that?

Comment: You could use this command to remove existing  rule: `appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/rewrite/globalRules /-"[name='http_redirect']" /commit:apphost`

Comment: is there any way to edit the value rather than using the + or -?

Comment: in my opinion, this is the way, you need to do some research to find another way. you could also use PowerShell command to add a rule. did you face any issue with + or - while creating rule?